# Prove that a particular sequence $l_n$ representing the amount of natural numbers $p$ satisfying $100n + 1 \le p^2 \le 100(n+1)$ is divergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

> Let a sequence $\{l_n\}, n \in \Bbb N$ denote the amount of natural numbers $p \in \Bbb N$ which satisfy the following inequality:
>   $$
> 100n + 1 \le p^2 \le 100(n+1)
> $$ 
>   Prove $\{l_n\}$ diverges.

This is a bit tricky at first glance but lets try to track down what the inequality actually means. This is nothing but a set of intervals in the form $[100n + 1; 100(n+1)]$, or for the first several numbers:
$$
[101, 200], [201, 300], [301, 400], \dots [100n + 1, 100(n+1)]
$$

None of the first $10$ natural numbers get into the range $[101, +\infty]$. Let $N(s)$ be a function which takes a set and outputs the amount of elements in that set. Lets write down several terms of $\{l_n\}$:
$$
l_1 = N(\{p: 101 \le p^2 \le 200\}) = N(\{11, 12, 13, 14\}) = 4 \\
l_2 = N(\{p: 201 \le p^2 \le 300\}) = N(\{15, 16, 17\}) = 3 \\
\dots \\
l_6 = N(\{p: 601 \le p^2 \le 700\}) = N(\{25, 26\}) = 2 \\
\dots
$$

Clearly the number of squares which gets into the range with length $100$ is starting to decrease while $p$ is increasing, so eventually we will either get $1$ or $0$ for $l_n$ given $n$ is large enough.

This means we could choose two subsequences say $l_{n_k}$ and $l_{n_p}$ such that:
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} l_{n_k} = 1\\
\lim_{p\to\infty} l_{n_p} = 0
$$

Which would mean that the sequence $\{l_n\}$ is divergent.

The thoughts above are very informal and in my opinion are not rigorous enough to be considered a valid proof.

Could someone please show how those thoughts may have been formalized? I would also like to use a similar approach for $n^k + 1\le p^{k+1} \le (n+1)^k$ given some fixed $k \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: Determine a close expression for N, function of n.

Comment: @Dude, is this possible? I mean how could i know whether a particular square gets in some range? I'm not sure i posses the necessary knowledge for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strategy looks good, you just need to find those $2$ subsequences:

---

Here is a subsequence $\left\{l_{k^2+2k}\right\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that
$$\color{blue}{\left(10\cdot\left(k+1\right)-1\right)^2}=
100k^2+180k+81< \\
\color{red}{100\cdot \left(k^2+2k\right) + 1 }
\leq p=\color{blue}{10^2\cdot(k+1)^2}=
\color{red}{100\cdot\left(\left(k^2+2k\right)+1\right)}$$
where each $l_{k^2+2k}=1$, (in red are the boundaries, in blue $2$ consecutive perfect squares).

---

And a subsequence $\left\{l_{k^2+2k+1}\right\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that
$$\color{blue}{10^2\cdot\left(k+1\right)^2}< \\
\color{red}{100\cdot \left(k^2+2k+1\right) + 1} <
\color{red}{100\cdot\left(\left(k^2+2k+1\right)+1\right)}=\\
100\cdot\left(k^2+2k+2\right)<100k^2+220k+121=
\color{blue}{\left(10\cdot(k+1)+1\right)^2}$$
where each $l_{k^2+2k+1}=0$ (for $k\geq 4$).

Comment: wow, that's amazing! Thank you for your help! How would you come up with such subsequences? Have you guessed them or rather derive them in another way?

Comment: It started with the idea of making $n+1$ a perfect square, so that $100(n+1)=10^2 (n+1)$ becomes a perfect square as well (and a boundary value). Everything else are just calculations ...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: to determine a close expression for $N$, take square roots from both sides of the inequality:$$100n+1\le p^2 \le 100(n+1)$$ and...

Comment: But $N$ denotes the number of elements in the set, how can you derive any expression for $N$ based on that inequality?